# GC_FOR_ALLOC log messages and screen goes blank when clicking on links to switch intents

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is the default activity that is loaded when the code it run. 
When I click on the create new account link the screen goes blank and the GC_FOR_ALLOC log messages start to appear. There seems to be a problem when switching to the next activity (create new account page). i've tried it both on my sony xperia z1 and on the geny motion emulator, the same results happen.

```
package com.michaelsony.gcsemathsrevisionapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class LoginPage extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final String TAG = "Michael's Message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);
    Log.i(TAG, "OnCreate");
    }

public void onClick(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, CreateAccount.class);
    startActivity(i);
}




@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(TAG, "onStart");
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(TAG, "onPause");
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.i(TAG, "onStop");
}


@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.i(TAG, "onRestart");
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
}


@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login_page, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

This is the activity I am trying to switch to

```
package com.michaelsony.gcsemathsrevisionapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;


public class CreateAccount extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText firstnamebox, surnamebox, usernamebox, passwordbox, confirmpassbox;
UserDBHandler dbHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_account);
    firstnamebox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstnamebox);
    surnamebox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.surnamebox);
    usernamebox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernamebox);
    passwordbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordbox);
    confirmpassbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirmpassbox);
    dbHandler = new UserDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
    printDatabase();
}
//Add a user to the database(create a user)
public void createAccountClick(View view){
    Users user = new Users(firstnamebox.getText().toString(),     surnamebox.getText().toString(), usernamebox.getText().toString(), passwordbox.getText().toString(), confirmpassbox.getText().toString());
    Log.d("app1", "Password=" + passwordbox.getText().toString() + " confirm=" + confirmpassbox.getText().toString());
    //dbHandler.addUser(user);
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Account Created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          if(!passwordbox.getText().toString().equals(confirmpassbox.getText().toString()))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Passwords Do Not      Match",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()    ;
        passwordbox.setText("");
        confirmpassbox.setText("");
        Log.d("app1", "Password=" + passwordbox.getText().toString() + "      confirm=" + confirmpassbox.getText().toString());
         }
    else
    {
      dbHandler.addUser(user);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Account Created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
        Log.d("app1", "Password=" + passwordbox.getText().toString() + " confirm=" + confirmpassbox.getText().toString());

    }



}

public void printDatabase(){
    String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_create_account, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

the log messages are as follows:

```
05-09 13:34:51.371    1941-1941/com.michaelsony.gcsemathsrevisionapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 279K, 12% free 4248K/4776K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
05-09 13:34:51.395    1941-1941/com.michaelsony.gcsemathsrevisionapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 155K, 12% free 4216K/4776K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
05-09 13:34:51.399    1941-1941/com.michaelsony.gcsemathsrevisionapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 279K, 12% free 4248K/4776K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
05-09 13:34:51.415    1941-1941/com.michaelsony.gcsemathsrevisionapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 155K, 12% free 4216K/4776K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
05-09 13:34:51.435    1941-1941/com.michaelsony.gcsemathsrevisionapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 279K, 12% free 4248K/4776K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
05-09 13:34:51.447    1941-1941/com.michaelsony.gcsemathsrevisionapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 155K, 12% free 4216K/4776K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
05-09 13:34:51.455    1941-1941/com.michaelsony.gcsemathsrevisionapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 280K, 12% free 4248K/4776K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
```

These are just a few they keep flooding the logcat!

Comment: Please add the missing messages from logcat. It will give people more information to help you.

Comment: I have now added the logcat messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don's use the `onClick` as a method name, name it something else

```
public void onClick(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, CreateAccount.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Like

```
public void onCreateAccountClicked(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(LoginPage.this, CreateAccount.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

And avoid printing the whole database. It may be big and take up a lot of memory, that will cause an excessive calling the GC (when it starts to run low on memory) and eventually crash the app as it finally runs out of memory.

```
public void printDatabase(){
    //String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
}
```

Comment: Just tried this, still getting the same logcat messages

Comment: try not to print the db in the second activity, maybe it's too big